# Setup qmake for Qt Creator on Mac

Tags: qt, installation, osx-snow-leopard, qt-creator, qmake

I installed the qt debug and release libraries and qt creator.

I can't make it build because of qmake. How can i make qt creator know of `qmake`?

I went to `Preferences->Build&Run` and click `Add` but I can't select anything, not even `qmake` after I find it.

I have qmake, I can run it from the command line but I can't make the `QtCreator` know about it.

Please help me, I feel like I'm gonna blow up.

Thanks

Comment: 2.1.x: Tools -> Options -> Qt4 -> `+`

Comment: version 2.5.2, i can click + or Add on the Preferences->Buld&Run->QtVersions but i can't select anything. I don't know why :(
I'm angry as hell....

Comment: i installed the libraries for version 4.6.4 because i'm using a 32bit mac and it's the only ones that run on 32 from what i read. Still can't get it work, it's 2 days i'm struggling now

Comment: The way I'm used to is that when you click on `+` you select the qmake binary in the "open file" dialog which pops up. Maybe you could add a screenshot to your question? It *might* be the case (but I hope this is not true) that QtCreator rejects such an old version of Qt. If this really is the case, you could try to build 4.8.x from source; should be possible.

Comment: Ok, in QtCreator 2.5.x the setting is under Options -> Build & Run -> Qt versions -> Add, then enter a name for it and click on `Browse...` to browse for the qmake binary. Please tell me what *exactly* behaves unexpected in your case. This is the official guide: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-master/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: Ah and note that this only adds a Qt version, but you still have to configure the so-called "Target" in the other tab. Add a target which uses this Qt version. This target is then used for projects. You can think about targets being the combination of Qt version and C++ tool chain (at least I think it is that xD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was browse a file in `/usr/bin` (which is hidden in Mac OS X) which set the default folder that comes out in the file explorer to `/usr/bin`. Then I browsed for `qmake` which drove me in /usr/bin so i can select qmake. That's a workaround however.

Comment: I found that qmake is an alias to qmake-4.8 and I could not select it. So I deleted the qmake alias and renamed qmake-4.8 to qmake. I don't know what repercussions this causes though XD

Answer (score 1):

On qt creator 4.1.0, open the Build&Run Preferences.

Under Qt Version click "Add" and hit:
*Command + shift + G*

and then type: /usr/local/bin (or whereever your qmake is: `find qmake`)

In order to see the new qt version in *Kits* you need to hit OK and re-open the Preferences window

I use Mac version 10.11.6 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an ownership issue.  Try chown on /usr/bin/qmake and re-try Adding to Qt Versions.